# ethereumjs-tx is archived, what should I use for getSenderPublicKey()?

Tags: public-key

I'm playing Capture The Ether game: https://capturetheether.com/challenges/accounts/public-key/

Now I need to recover the public key from raw transaction. I found these online:

```
const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
const msg = 'xxx'

let tx = new EthereumTx(msg, 4)
console.log(tx.getSenderPublicKey())
console.log(tx.getSenderAddress())
```

But since [ethereumjs-tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx) is deprecated in 2020, what should I use now?